# Can anyone please help me to find the generalized equation for $x$,$y$ and $z$?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$$
A= P(9+2\cos(x)+2\cos(y)+2\cos(z))
$$
$$
B= P(9+2\cos(x-2\pi/3)+2\cos(y-2\pi/3)+2\cos(z-2\pi/3))
$$
$$
C= P(9+2\cos(x+2\pi/3)+2\cos(y+2\pi/3)+2\cos(z+2\pi/3))
$$

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: Sorry that i didn't use LATEX. But it's formatted already. Thanks Mr. Carser.

Comment: I take it that A, B, C, p are known constants?

Comment: what is $p(x)$ ?

Comment: yeah. A,B,C, p are unknown constants. @ Mr. John Hughes

Comment: Step 1: Let $A' = A/p; B' = B/p; C' = C/p$ and work from there.

Comment: P itself is a unknown constant. @ Igael

Comment: an answer will be appreciated @ John Hughes

Comment: Wait...you don't know $A,B,C,p, x, y, $ or $z$? Then at least one solution is easy: $p = A = B= C = 0$ and $x,y,z$ are any values.

Comment: Let me be clear: you have three equations in (apparently) seven unknowns. There's likely to be a 4-parameter family of solutions. This makes me think that you perhaps don't know quite what you're asking, and need to formulate your question better. Can you tell us the form that a satisfactory answer might take? Do you want actual numbers for $A,B,C,p,x,y,z$?

Comment: x,y,z are the phase of three waves and ABC are power/amplitudes! I can measure A,B,C and p. but x,y,z to be calculated.

Comment: three unknowns (x,y and z) and three equations. I need generalized  equation for X,Y and Z. @  John

Comment: @mican - Interesting question for electric engineers. Do you have the values of A, B, C, P? Is your system balanced or unbalanced? Or you do not know and you are trying to determine which phase is malfunctioning?

Comment: @mican -  WAIT A MINUTE!! What you call x, y, z, instead of being three different values, they are the same: they are the "frequency". If your system is balanced, phases are shifted 120 degrees = $ 2\pi/3 $. If your system is not balanced, phases will be not shifted 120 degrees = $ 2\pi/3 $, and we will have to determine them. Can you give more information. And read this http://www.elect.mrt.ac.lk/EE201_3phase_sym_comp.pdf

Comment: OK. Well, unless the sum $A+B+C$ is exactly $9p$, your system of equations has no solutions, as my answer shows. If it *is* exactly $9p$, then you've actually got a problem that might be worth solving.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: replacing $A,B,C$ with $A/p$, etc., we have
\begin{align}
A&= (9+2\cos(x)+2\cos(y)+2\cos(z))\\
B&= (9+2\cos(x-2\pi/3)+2\cos(y-2\pi/3)+2\cos(z-2\pi/3))\\
C&= (9+2\cos(x+2\pi/3)+2\cos(y+2\pi/3)+2\cos(z+2\pi/3))
\end{align}

Summing, we get
\begin{align}
A+B+C&= 27 + 2[\cos(x) + \cos(x-2\pi/3) + \cos(x + 2\pi/3] + \ldots \end{align}
where the ellipses denote similar expressions in $y$ and $z$. But this expression in brackets is always zero, so these equations cannot have a solution unless $A + B + C = 27$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Like John Hughes said first introduce $A'=A/p$, $B'=B/p$ and $C'=C/p$ assuming $p\neq0$. Only if $A=B=C=0$ allows $p=0$ which means that any combination of $x,y,z$ solves the problem.

Then use the addition formula

$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$

Then replace $\sin(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$ (assuming $x \in [0,\pi]$), same for $y$ and $z$. And substitute $\cos(x)=\alpha_1$. Do the same with $\cos(y)=\alpha_2$ and $\cos(z)=\alpha_3$. Solve the nonlinear system.

Comment: still I'm not clear about the answer. on a short note, x,y,z ∈ [0,2π]

Comment: If $x,y,z \in [0,2\pi]$ then you will need to make a case by case examination of 8 cases. $x,y,z \in [0,\pi]$, only $z \in[\pi,2\pi]$, only $y \in [\pi,2\pi]$, only $x \in [\pi,2\pi]$, and so forth. Whenever a variable is $\in [\pi,2\pi]$ just place a minus sign in front of the square root.